# Java Spark SQL - CSV Inferschema custom

Tags: java, scala, csv, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am looking into building a customized Spark SQL `CSV` inferschema to identify custom datatypes (those that are not identified with the `inferschema` option). I am using a `StringIndexer` to get unique categorical values to identify the custom data types.

```
String[] categoricalStringValues = new StringIndexer().setInputCol(columnName).fit(dataframe).labels();

// Code to identify/guess the most likely custom datatype
// some examples: currency ($12.00), percent (24.05%) etc
```

The process is painfully slow. I have found the `CSVInferSchema` in scala code. Is there a way in which this class can be invoked or used or interpreted to develop a code to identify custom datatypes?

[CSVInferSchema.scala](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/csv/CSVInferSchema.scala)

[DataTypes](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/types/DataTypes.html)